Asyncio: Creating a producer-consumer flow with async generator output
I am trying to set up a asyncio program that takes as its input, one AsyncGenerator and returns data via another AsyncGenerator. Here's a sample program that illustrates the basic flow of data:
from collections.abc import AsyncGenerator
import asyncio

async def input_gen() -> AsyncGenerator[str, None]:
    '''a simple generator that yields strings'''
    for char in "abc123xyz789":
        await asyncio.sleep(0.1)
        yield char


async def slow_task(item: str) -> str:
    '''simulate a slow task that opporates on a single item'''
    await asyncio.sleep(0.5)
    return f"{item}_loaded"


async def my_gen() -> AsyncGenerator[str, None]:
    '''a second generator that yields the results slow_task(item)'''
    async for item in input_gen():
        yield await slow_task(item)

results = [x async for x in my_gen()]

In this flow, I would like to a) enable concurrent processing of slow_tasks for each item, and b) start yielding the outputs of slow_task(item) as soon as they become available. The outputs of my_gen need not be sorted but should be otherwise identically.
I have been trying to find a path to do this using asyncio's Queue in a producer/consumer pattern but I haven't managed to get very far. I'm hoping folks have some suggestions for approaches that will improve this.

Here is an example how you can create producer-consumer flow using async generator (using 2 queues):
import asyncio
import random
from collections.abc import AsyncGenerator


async def input_gen() -> AsyncGenerator[str, None]:
    """a simple generator that yields strings"""
    for char in "abc123xyz789":
        await asyncio.sleep(0.1)
        yield char
        print(f"{char=} produced...")


async def slow_task(input_queue: asyncio.Queue, output_queue: asyncio.Queue) -> str:
    """simulate a slow task that opporates on a single item"""
    while True:
        item = await input_queue.get()
        await asyncio.sleep(random.random() + 0.2)
        print(f"{item=} handled...")
        output_queue.put_nowait(f"{item}_loaded")
        input_queue.task_done()


async def main():
    input_queue = asyncio.Queue()
    output_queue = asyncio.Queue()

    # create 4 tasks that wait for items in the `input_queue` and
    # put results to `outuput_queue`
    slow_tasks = [
        asyncio.create_task(slow_task(input_queue, output_queue)) for _ in range(4)
    ]

    # tasks are created, so wait for inputs and put them to `input_queue`
    async for item in input_gen():
        input_queue.put_nowait(item)

    # wait for all items to be handled
    await input_queue.join()

    # gather all results from output queue
    result = []
    while not output_queue.empty():
        result.append(await output_queue.get())
        output_queue.task_done()

    print(result)


asyncio.run(main())

Prints (for example):
char='a' produced...
char='b' produced...
char='c' produced...
char='1' produced...
char='2' produced...
item='c' handled...
item='b' handled...
char='3' produced...
item='1' handled...
char='x' produced...
char='y' produced...
item='3' handled...
item='a' handled...
char='z' produced...
char='7' produced...
char='8' produced...
char='9' produced...
item='x' handled...
item='z' handled...
item='7' handled...
item='y' handled...
item='2' handled...
item='9' handled...
item='8' handled...
['c_loaded', 'b_loaded', '1_loaded', '3_loaded', 'a_loaded', 'x_loaded', 'z_loaded', '7_loaded', 'y_loaded', '2_loaded', '9_loaded', '8_loaded']


Thanks @andrej-kesely! It's surprising to me that there aren't better abstractions for this in asyncio. I'm particularly worried about error handling and whatnot in this context. It would be nice if there was a tool that helped manage the queues, errors, concurrency. But this does seem to work!

I should note that also recently found aiostream which seems to provide some of the abstractions that you might want here. I'll post that answer below.

Here's a solution I found using aiostream:
import asyncio
from collections.abc import AsyncGenerator
from aiostream import stream, async_, pipe

async def input_gen() -> AsyncGenerator[str, None]:
    '''a simple generator that yields strings'''
    for char in "abc123xyz789":
        await asyncio.sleep(0.1)
        yield char


async def slow_task(item: str) -> str:
    '''simulate a slow task that opporates on a single item'''
    await asyncio.sleep(0.5)
    return f"{item}_loaded"


async def my_gen() -> AsyncGenerator[str, None]:
    '''a second generator that yields the results slow_task(item)'''
    async for item in input_gen():
        yield await slow_task(item)

ys = stream.map(input_gen(), async_(slow_task))
results = [x async for x in ys]

The only problem with this approach is that aiostream has a GPL license so I can't use it in my project, but it may be useful to others so sharing it here.
